# Laravel delete linked model's data by user_id in booted function of User model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've read part of the [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events-using-closures) docs for events and closures for models, I've got various models in my project whereby a user may have data linked to them in another table by a `user_id` column, the `user_id` column that I have in my various tables is structured as an unsigned integer *(I'm aware I could've gone with a foreignId column by kind of a legacy approach here)*

It looks like:

```php
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
```

I'd like to delete user data by their ID within these other tables and rather than creating a delete function and grabbing each model I want to delete data against, I've utilised the closure `booted` function and what I believe to be an event to listen and delete related model data, but I experience an error when trying to delete my user account, other data in other tables isn't deleted, the error I get is:

> Call to undefined method App\Models\User::releationship()

My user model looks like:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject, MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable, SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
      return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
      return [];
    }

    /**
     * Route notifications for the Slack channel.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Notifications\Notification  $notification
     * @return string
     */
    public function routeNotificationForSlack($notification)
    {
        $url = $this->slack_webhook;
        $webhook = (isset($url) && !empty($url)) ? $url : null;

        return $webhook;
    }

    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::deleted(function ($model) {
            $model->relationship()->delete();
        });
    }
}
```

And an example *(of many)* model I have, `UptimeChecks` looks like:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UptimeChecks extends Model
{

    /**
    * The table associated with the model.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $table = 'uptime_checks';

    /**
    * Join user table
    */
    public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

All is then kicked off by a `deleteAccount` function in my API, which is deleting the user's account, but isn't deleting data in other tables. **What am I missing and how could I do a check to make sure other data is deleted before confirming to the user that their account and linked data is gone?**

```php
/**
 * Delete account
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function deleteAccount(Request $request)
{

    // attempt to delete account
    try {

        $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::id());
        $user->delete();

        // everything went okay!
        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'message' => 'Your account has been deleted'], 200);

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        // catch the error
        return response()->json(['success' => false, 'message' => 'We was unable to delete your account at this time'], 422);

    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your relationship named "relationship" on the user?

Comment: @mrhn am I mistaken? I'm not sure what you mean, I'm new to this part of Laravel and assumed based on another similar question that I needed to add that - do you have a code example correction please?

Comment: You are deleting the "relationship" on the user $model->relationship()->delete(); In laravel you define relationships. Do you have an enxample of which table you want to delete from?'

Comment: I want to delete from the table `uptime_checks`, which is the Model `UptimeChecks` as per the description and any other table with a `user_id` too. (all models are similar in my app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Laravel`, when doing `$model->relationship()->delete();` you will need to have the relationship defined and relationship() seems like it is copy pasted code snippet. Simply add the relationship to your `User` model.

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject, MustVerifyEmail
{
    ...
    public function uptimeChecks() {
        return $this->hasMany(UptimeChecks::class);
    }
}
```

Now you can access and delete the relationship in your boot method.

```
$model->uptimeChecks()->delete();
```

Comment: So if I've got 5 tables, would I effectively need the above function x5 for whatever tables I want to delete?

Comment: It is always best in laravel to define models and relationship, both for readability and it is easier to work with that :) There would be a generic approach, but i would never recommend that, whatever you gain in easy to create is gonna be added to the confusion of your solution.

Comment: Great, seems to be working anyway, but realised that one of my models doesn't have a `user_id` column, instead it's a `team_id` _(it's the same but named differently for a future change)_, can't find how I could effectively overwrite the `$this->hasMany(NotificationContact::class);` to use a different column for that specific table?

Comment: The second and third parameters are foreign key and local_key to overwrite relationship columns. $this->hasMany(NotificationContact::class, 'team_id'); should suffice

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a function in User.php

```
public function uptimeCheck()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\UptimeChecks');
}
```

and change the boot function

> $model->uptimeCheck()->delete();

This way you need to do for all related relations.

Answer (score 0):

This probably should be: `$model->user()->delete()` instead. There's nothing else.

If this shouldn't be the intention, reconsider the direction of the relationship.